# UIStackView inside UITableViewCell: constraints not enabled

Tags: swift, uitableview, layout, storyboard, uistackview

I have a horizontal `UIStackView` inside a `UITableViewCell`. Why can't I add constraints related to cell's content view in Storyboard?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If stackview ' layout is selected `Translates Mask Into Constraints` on Size Inspector' View page

[image]

You can't add constraints.
Change it with `Automatic`